# What are typical career paths for PMs as they gain in experience and become more senior?

Tags: career

As Project Managers become more senior, what are the typical career paths (beyond just taking on larger and more complex projects)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Portfolio management
- Strategic decision making positions
- Leaders of innovation initiatives and new growth opportunities

Answer (score 1):

**All the way up to COO**

As your experience with larger/higher-budget/more-complex projects grows, you'll eventually be in a position to manage projects which directly affect the business in all areas, e.g. rolling out company-wide strategic initiatives. With enough experience in this, there's no reason you couldn't be invited to help decide on the initiatives in the first place.